# How to Create java annotation methods in latest cordova version (above 5.0.0)

Tags: javascript, cordova

How do you create JavaScript annotation methods in java, using the latest version of Cordova? How do you access those methods in javascript?

```
 @JavascriptInterface
 public String getservice_id()
 {
      String service_id= mGap.getString(R.string.service_id);
      return service_id;

 }
```

Create bridge between java and javascript for example:

```
 MyClass   mc = new MyClass(this, appView);
 appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "security");

 Javascript- Accessing native code in javascript

 funtion getserviceid()
 {
     alert(window.security.getservice_id);
 }
```

How would you write this in a Cordova application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
((SystemWebView)appView.getView()).addJavascriptInterface(mc, "security");
```